# Show that $\int_a^bg(x).f(x)dx$ = $\frac{-1}{c}\int_a^bg(x).f'(x)dx$

Tags: calculus

(i) f is an infinitely differentiable function that is identically zero at a and b (that is f^(n)(a) = f^(n)(b)= 0 for every n).

(ii) g is a differentiable function such that g'(x) = cg(x)

So with the above two conditions I suppose I have to prove that:

$\int_a^bg(x).f(x)dx$ = $\int_a^bg'(x).f'(x)dx$

For f(x) = f '(x) I just presumed that they both = 0 according to the first condition.

For g(x) = g'(x)   I can see how taking out (1/c) will remove the c, but I don't understand why it is negative. Thank you for any help.

Comment: You do only integration by part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is plain old integration by parts. Note that $\int g(x) dx = \frac{1}{c} g(x)$ (take derivatives on both sides to get $g'(x) = cg(x)$). Now:

\begin{align}
\int_a^b \underbrace{f(x)}_{u} \underbrace{g(x) dx}_{dv} &=  \left. \frac{1}{c} g(x) f(x) \right|_a^b - \int_a^b \frac{1}{c} g(x) f'(x) dx\\
&= 0 - \frac{1}{c} \int_a^b g(x) f'(x) dx
\end{align}

---

Note: Since $f^{(n)}$ is zero at $a$ and $b$ for all $n$, you can run further with this, and say that

\begin{align}
\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx &=  \left(\frac{-1}{c}\right)^n \int_a^b g(x) f^{(n)}(x) dx
\end{align}